# Is calling "npm install" on a package of a specific (older) version expected to stay the same over time?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json, npm-scripts

I'm using an older version of node (6.17.1) and had explicitly installed eslint@5.16.0 as the newer versions of eslint don't work with node 6. This had been working without any problems for a while.

Recently, when installing eslint@5.16.0 from package.json using `npm install` no longer works -- there is now an incompatible dependency that I assume is somewhere in eslint's dependency tree.

My question is, was `npm install` on a specific version of eslint expected to continue working forever in the same way? Or is this normal for npm packages (of a specific version) to have some package deep in the dependency tree change, and then break that specific version of the first package?

And if this cannot be prevented, is there any way to easily fix this once a dependency breaks? Is this what package-lock.json is for?

The error output from npm is below:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 18.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.17.1/bin/node" "/Users/~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.17.1/bin/npm" "install" "eslint@5.16.0"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported engine for esquery@1.2.0: wanted: {"node":">=8.0"} (current: {"node":"6.17.1","npm":"3.10.10"})
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: esquery@1.2.0
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: esquery@1.2.0
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">=8.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"3.10.10","node":"6.17.1"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you aluded to, this is what the lock file (`package-lock.json` for `npm` and `yarn.lock` for `yarn`) is for. Otherwise, `npm` will look for the latest package version that satisfy the constraints, for both the package you specified as well as its dependencies, and their dependencies, and so on.

However, `package-lock.json` was only introduced in [npm v5](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500), and so your current version of `npm` (v3.10.10) won't have a `package-lock.json`. You'd instead need to use [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap). I'd advice you to use `yarn` in the future if you are not able to update your version of Node.js.

From your error output, it seems like `esquery` requires an [engine](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines) version of Node.js v8 or above. By using a newer version of Node.js, and running `yarn why esquery` to see why it's required, it seems like it's depended on directly by `eslint`.

```
$ yarn why esquery
yarn why v1.22.4
[1/4] Why do we have the module "esquery"...?
[2/4] Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4] Finding dependency...
[4/4] Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "esquery@1.2.0"
info Reasons this module exists
   - "eslint" depends on it
   - Hoisted from "eslint#esquery"
info Disk size without dependencies: "744KB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "796KB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "796KB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 1
Done in 0.12s.
```

ESLint v5.16.0 specifies a dependency on `esquery` using the [caret range](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) `^1.0.1` which means it will use the latest version of `esquery` provided the major version is still `1`. This was fine until esquery v1.1.0, since it [supported Node.js v0.6 and above](https://github.com/estools/esquery/blob/v1.1.0/package.json#L35); but in v1.2.0, this was [changed to v8 and above](https://github.com/estools/esquery/blob/v1.2.0/package.json#L69).

Since this is, evidently, a breaking change, if the authors were abiding by [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](https://semver.org/), they should have bumped the version number to v2.0.0 instead of v1.2.0, but nowhere in the `README.md` does it says it's following semver.

The proper fix would be to create a PR on the `eslint` repository proposing to change the version range from `^1.0.1` to `1.1.x` (or `~1.1`), but for now, you can try using this `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, which specifies the `1.1.0` version of esquery.

```
{
  "name": "sonpminstall",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/code-frame": {
      "version": "7.8.3",
      "from": "@babel/code-frame@>=7.0.0 <8.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/code-frame/-/code-frame-7.8.3.tgz"
    },
    "@babel/helper-validator-identifier": {
      "version": "7.9.0",
      "from": "@babel/helper-validator-identifier@>=7.9.0 <8.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/helper-validator-identifier/-/helper-validator-identifier-7.9.0.tgz"
    },
    "@babel/highlight": {
      "version": "7.9.0",
      "from": "@babel/highlight@>=7.8.3 <8.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/highlight/-/highlight-7.9.0.tgz"
    },
    "acorn": {
      "version": "6.4.1",
      "from": "acorn@>=6.0.7 <7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-6.4.1.tgz"
    },
    "acorn-jsx": {
      "version": "5.2.0",
      "from": "acorn-jsx@>=5.0.0 <6.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn-jsx/-/acorn-jsx-5.2.0.tgz"
    },
    "ajv": {
      "version": "6.12.0",
      "from": "ajv@>=6.9.1 <7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ajv/-/ajv-6.12.0.tgz"
    },
    "ansi-escapes": {
      "version": "3.2.0",
      "from": "ansi-escapes@>=3.2.0 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-escapes/-/ansi-escapes-3.2.0.tgz"
    },
    "ansi-regex": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "from": "ansi-regex@>=3.0.0 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-3.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "ansi-styles": {
      "version": "3.2.1",
      "from": "ansi-styles@>=3.2.1 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles/-/ansi-styles-3.2.1.tgz"
    },
    "argparse": {
      "version": "1.0.10",
      "from": "argparse@>=1.0.7 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse/-/argparse-1.0.10.tgz"
    },
    "astral-regex": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "from": "astral-regex@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/astral-regex/-/astral-regex-1.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "balanced-match": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "from": "balanced-match@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/balanced-match/-/balanced-match-1.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "brace-expansion": {
      "version": "1.1.11",
      "from": "brace-expansion@>=1.1.7 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/brace-expansion/-/brace-expansion-1.1.11.tgz"
    },
    "callsites": {
      "version": "3.1.0",
      "from": "callsites@>=3.0.0 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/callsites/-/callsites-3.1.0.tgz"
    },
    "chalk": {
      "version": "2.4.2",
      "from": "chalk@>=2.1.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk/-/chalk-2.4.2.tgz"
    },
    "chardet": {
      "version": "0.7.0",
      "from": "chardet@>=0.7.0 <0.8.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/chardet/-/chardet-0.7.0.tgz"
    },
    "cli-cursor": {
      "version": "2.1.0",
      "from": "cli-cursor@>=2.1.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cli-cursor/-/cli-cursor-2.1.0.tgz"
    },
    "cli-width": {
      "version": "2.2.0",
      "from": "cli-width@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cli-width/-/cli-width-2.2.0.tgz"
    },
    "color-convert": {
      "version": "1.9.3",
      "from": "color-convert@>=1.9.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/color-convert/-/color-convert-1.9.3.tgz"
    },
    "color-name": {
      "version": "1.1.3",
      "from": "color-name@1.1.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/color-name/-/color-name-1.1.3.tgz"
    },
    "concat-map": {
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "from": "concat-map@0.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/concat-map/-/concat-map-0.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "cross-spawn": {
      "version": "6.0.5",
      "from": "cross-spawn@>=6.0.5 <7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cross-spawn/-/cross-spawn-6.0.5.tgz"
    },
    "debug": {
      "version": "4.1.1",
      "from": "debug@>=4.0.1 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-4.1.1.tgz"
    },
    "deep-is": {
      "version": "0.1.3",
      "from": "deep-is@>=0.1.3 <0.2.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-is/-/deep-is-0.1.3.tgz"
    },
    "doctrine": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "from": "doctrine@>=3.0.0 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/doctrine/-/doctrine-3.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "emoji-regex": {
      "version": "7.0.3",
      "from": "emoji-regex@>=7.0.1 <8.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/emoji-regex/-/emoji-regex-7.0.3.tgz"
    },
    "escape-string-regexp": {
      "version": "1.0.5",
      "from": "escape-string-regexp@>=1.0.5 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-string-regexp/-/escape-string-regexp-1.0.5.tgz"
    },
    "eslint": {
      "version": "5.16.0",
      "from": "eslint@>=5.16.0 <6.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint/-/eslint-5.16.0.tgz"
    },
    "eslint-scope": {
      "version": "4.0.3",
      "from": "eslint-scope@>=4.0.3 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-scope/-/eslint-scope-4.0.3.tgz"
    },
    "eslint-utils": {
      "version": "1.4.3",
      "from": "eslint-utils@>=1.3.1 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-utils/-/eslint-utils-1.4.3.tgz"
    },
    "eslint-visitor-keys": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "from": "eslint-visitor-keys@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint-visitor-keys/-/eslint-visitor-keys-1.1.0.tgz"
    },
    "espree": {
      "version": "5.0.1",
      "from": "espree@>=5.0.1 <6.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/espree/-/espree-5.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "esprima": {
      "version": "4.0.1",
      "from": "esprima@>=4.0.0 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima/-/esprima-4.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "esquery": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "from": "esquery@>=1.0.1 <1.2.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/esquery/-/esquery-1.1.0.tgz",
      "dependencies": {
        "estraverse": {
          "version": "4.0.0",
          "from": "estraverse@>=4.0.0 <5.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/estraverse/-/estraverse-4.0.0.tgz"
        }
      }
    },
    "esrecurse": {
      "version": "4.2.1",
      "from": "esrecurse@>=4.1.0 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/esrecurse/-/esrecurse-4.2.1.tgz"
    },
    "estraverse": {
      "version": "4.3.0",
      "from": "estraverse@>=4.1.1 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/estraverse/-/estraverse-4.3.0.tgz"
    },
    "esutils": {
      "version": "2.0.3",
      "from": "esutils@>=2.0.2 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/esutils/-/esutils-2.0.3.tgz"
    },
    "external-editor": {
      "version": "3.1.0",
      "from": "external-editor@>=3.0.3 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/external-editor/-/external-editor-3.1.0.tgz"
    },
    "fast-deep-equal": {
      "version": "3.1.1",
      "from": "fast-deep-equal@>=3.1.1 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fast-deep-equal/-/fast-deep-equal-3.1.1.tgz"
    },
    "fast-json-stable-stringify": {
      "version": "2.1.0",
      "from": "fast-json-stable-stringify@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fast-json-stable-stringify/-/fast-json-stable-stringify-2.1.0.tgz"
    },
    "fast-levenshtein": {
      "version": "2.0.6",
      "from": "fast-levenshtein@>=2.0.6 <2.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fast-levenshtein/-/fast-levenshtein-2.0.6.tgz"
    },
    "figures": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "from": "figures@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/figures/-/figures-2.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "file-entry-cache": {
      "version": "5.0.1",
      "from": "file-entry-cache@>=5.0.1 <6.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/file-entry-cache/-/file-entry-cache-5.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "flat-cache": {
      "version": "2.0.1",
      "from": "flat-cache@>=2.0.1 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/flat-cache/-/flat-cache-2.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "flatted": {
      "version": "2.0.1",
      "from": "flatted@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/flatted/-/flatted-2.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "fs.realpath": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "from": "fs.realpath@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fs.realpath/-/fs.realpath-1.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "functional-red-black-tree": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "from": "functional-red-black-tree@>=1.0.1 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/functional-red-black-tree/-/functional-red-black-tree-1.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "glob": {
      "version": "7.1.6",
      "from": "glob@>=7.1.2 <8.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-7.1.6.tgz"
    },
    "globals": {
      "version": "11.12.0",
      "from": "globals@>=11.7.0 <12.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/globals/-/globals-11.12.0.tgz"
    },
    "has-flag": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "from": "has-flag@>=3.0.0 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/has-flag/-/has-flag-3.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "iconv-lite": {
      "version": "0.4.24",
      "from": "iconv-lite@>=0.4.24 <0.5.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv-lite/-/iconv-lite-0.4.24.tgz"
    },
    "ignore": {
      "version": "4.0.6",
      "from": "ignore@>=4.0.6 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ignore/-/ignore-4.0.6.tgz"
    },
    "import-fresh": {
      "version": "3.2.1",
      "from": "import-fresh@>=3.0.0 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/import-fresh/-/import-fresh-3.2.1.tgz"
    },
    "imurmurhash": {
      "version": "0.1.4",
      "from": "imurmurhash@>=0.1.4 <0.2.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/imurmurhash/-/imurmurhash-0.1.4.tgz"
    },
    "inflight": {
      "version": "1.0.6",
      "from": "inflight@>=1.0.4 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/inflight/-/inflight-1.0.6.tgz"
    },
    "inherits": {
      "version": "2.0.4",
      "from": "inherits@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.4.tgz"
    },
    "inquirer": {
      "version": "6.5.2",
      "from": "inquirer@>=6.2.2 <7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer/-/inquirer-6.5.2.tgz",
      "dependencies": {
        "ansi-regex": {
          "version": "4.1.0",
          "from": "ansi-regex@>=4.1.0 <5.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-4.1.0.tgz"
        },
        "strip-ansi": {
          "version": "5.2.0",
          "from": "strip-ansi@>=5.1.0 <6.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-5.2.0.tgz"
        }
      }
    },
    "is-fullwidth-code-point": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "from": "is-fullwidth-code-point@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-fullwidth-code-point/-/is-fullwidth-code-point-2.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "is-promise": {
      "version": "2.1.0",
      "from": "is-promise@>=2.1.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-promise/-/is-promise-2.1.0.tgz"
    },
    "isexe": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "from": "isexe@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/isexe/-/isexe-2.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "js-tokens": {
      "version": "4.0.0",
      "from": "js-tokens@>=4.0.0 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/js-tokens/-/js-tokens-4.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "js-yaml": {
      "version": "3.13.1",
      "from": "js-yaml@>=3.13.0 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml/-/js-yaml-3.13.1.tgz"
    },
    "json-schema-traverse": {
      "version": "0.4.1",
      "from": "json-schema-traverse@>=0.4.1 <0.5.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema-traverse/-/json-schema-traverse-0.4.1.tgz"
    },
    "json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "from": "json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@>=1.0.1 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify/-/json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify-1.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "levn": {
      "version": "0.3.0",
      "from": "levn@>=0.3.0 <0.4.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/levn/-/levn-0.3.0.tgz"
    },
    "lodash": {
      "version": "4.17.15",
      "from": "lodash@>=4.17.11 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.15.tgz"
    },
    "mimic-fn": {
      "version": "1.2.0",
      "from": "mimic-fn@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mimic-fn/-/mimic-fn-1.2.0.tgz"
    },
    "minimatch": {
      "version": "3.0.4",
      "from": "minimatch@>=3.0.4 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-3.0.4.tgz"
    },
    "minimist": {
      "version": "1.2.5",
      "from": "minimist@>=1.2.5 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-1.2.5.tgz"
    },
    "mkdirp": {
      "version": "0.5.4",
      "from": "mkdirp@>=0.5.1 <0.6.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.5.4.tgz"
    },
    "ms": {
      "version": "2.1.2",
      "from": "ms@>=2.1.1 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-2.1.2.tgz"
    },
    "mute-stream": {
      "version": "0.0.7",
      "from": "mute-stream@0.0.7",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream/-/mute-stream-0.0.7.tgz"
    },
    "natural-compare": {
      "version": "1.4.0",
      "from": "natural-compare@>=1.4.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/natural-compare/-/natural-compare-1.4.0.tgz"
    },
    "nice-try": {
      "version": "1.0.5",
      "from": "nice-try@>=1.0.4 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/nice-try/-/nice-try-1.0.5.tgz"
    },
    "once": {
      "version": "1.4.0",
      "from": "once@>=1.3.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/once/-/once-1.4.0.tgz"
    },
    "onetime": {
      "version": "2.0.1",
      "from": "onetime@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/onetime/-/onetime-2.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "optionator": {
      "version": "0.8.3",
      "from": "optionator@>=0.8.2 <0.9.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/optionator/-/optionator-0.8.3.tgz"
    },
    "os-tmpdir": {
      "version": "1.0.2",
      "from": "os-tmpdir@>=1.0.2 <1.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/os-tmpdir/-/os-tmpdir-1.0.2.tgz"
    },
    "parent-module": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "from": "parent-module@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/parent-module/-/parent-module-1.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "path-is-absolute": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "from": "path-is-absolute@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/path-is-absolute/-/path-is-absolute-1.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "path-is-inside": {
      "version": "1.0.2",
      "from": "path-is-inside@>=1.0.2 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/path-is-inside/-/path-is-inside-1.0.2.tgz"
    },
    "path-key": {
      "version": "2.0.1",
      "from": "path-key@>=2.0.1 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/path-key/-/path-key-2.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "prelude-ls": {
      "version": "1.1.2",
      "from": "prelude-ls@>=1.1.2 <1.2.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/prelude-ls/-/prelude-ls-1.1.2.tgz"
    },
    "progress": {
      "version": "2.0.3",
      "from": "progress@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/progress/-/progress-2.0.3.tgz"
    },
    "punycode": {
      "version": "2.1.1",
      "from": "punycode@>=2.1.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode/-/punycode-2.1.1.tgz"
    },
    "regexpp": {
      "version": "2.0.1",
      "from": "regexpp@>=2.0.1 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/regexpp/-/regexpp-2.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "resolve-from": {
      "version": "4.0.0",
      "from": "resolve-from@>=4.0.0 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve-from/-/resolve-from-4.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "restore-cursor": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "from": "restore-cursor@>=2.0.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/restore-cursor/-/restore-cursor-2.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "rimraf": {
      "version": "2.6.3",
      "from": "rimraf@2.6.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf/-/rimraf-2.6.3.tgz"
    },
    "run-async": {
      "version": "2.4.0",
      "from": "run-async@>=2.2.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/run-async/-/run-async-2.4.0.tgz"
    },
    "rxjs": {
      "version": "6.5.4",
      "from": "rxjs@>=6.4.0 <7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-6.5.4.tgz"
    },
    "safer-buffer": {
      "version": "2.1.2",
      "from": "safer-buffer@>=2.1.2 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/safer-buffer/-/safer-buffer-2.1.2.tgz"
    },
    "semver": {
      "version": "5.7.1",
      "from": "semver@>=5.5.1 <6.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/semver/-/semver-5.7.1.tgz"
    },
    "shebang-command": {
      "version": "1.2.0",
      "from": "shebang-command@>=1.2.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/shebang-command/-/shebang-command-1.2.0.tgz"
    },
    "shebang-regex": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "from": "shebang-regex@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/shebang-regex/-/shebang-regex-1.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "signal-exit": {
      "version": "3.0.2",
      "from": "signal-exit@>=3.0.2 <4.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/signal-exit/-/signal-exit-3.0.2.tgz"
    },
    "slice-ansi": {
      "version": "2.1.0",
      "from": "slice-ansi@>=2.1.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/slice-ansi/-/slice-ansi-2.1.0.tgz"
    },
    "sprintf-js": {
      "version": "1.0.3",
      "from": "sprintf-js@>=1.0.2 <1.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sprintf-js/-/sprintf-js-1.0.3.tgz"
    },
    "string-width": {
      "version": "2.1.1",
      "from": "string-width@>=2.1.0 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/string-width/-/string-width-2.1.1.tgz"
    },
    "strip-ansi": {
      "version": "4.0.0",
      "from": "strip-ansi@>=4.0.0 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-4.0.0.tgz"
    },
    "strip-json-comments": {
      "version": "2.0.1",
      "from": "strip-json-comments@>=2.0.1 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-json-comments/-/strip-json-comments-2.0.1.tgz"
    },
    "supports-color": {
      "version": "5.5.0",
      "from": "supports-color@>=5.3.0 <6.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color/-/supports-color-5.5.0.tgz"
    },
    "table": {
      "version": "5.4.6",
      "from": "table@>=5.2.3 <6.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/table/-/table-5.4.6.tgz",
      "dependencies": {
        "ansi-regex": {
          "version": "4.1.0",
          "from": "ansi-regex@>=4.1.0 <5.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex/-/ansi-regex-4.1.0.tgz"
        },
        "string-width": {
          "version": "3.1.0",
          "from": "string-width@>=3.0.0 <4.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/string-width/-/string-width-3.1.0.tgz"
        },
        "strip-ansi": {
          "version": "5.2.0",
          "from": "strip-ansi@>=5.1.0 <6.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi/-/strip-ansi-5.2.0.tgz"
        }
      }
    },
    "text-table": {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "from": "text-table@>=0.2.0 <0.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/text-table/-/text-table-0.2.0.tgz"
    },
    "through": {
      "version": "2.3.8",
      "from": "through@>=2.3.6 <3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/through/-/through-2.3.8.tgz"
    },
    "tmp": {
      "version": "0.0.33",
      "from": "tmp@>=0.0.33 <0.0.34",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tmp/-/tmp-0.0.33.tgz"
    },
    "tslib": {
      "version": "1.11.1",
      "from": "tslib@>=1.9.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tslib/-/tslib-1.11.1.tgz"
    },
    "type-check": {
      "version": "0.3.2",
      "from": "type-check@>=0.3.2 <0.4.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/type-check/-/type-check-0.3.2.tgz"
    },
    "uri-js": {
      "version": "4.2.2",
      "from": "uri-js@>=4.2.2 <5.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/uri-js/-/uri-js-4.2.2.tgz"
    },
    "which": {
      "version": "1.3.1",
      "from": "which@>=1.2.9 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/which/-/which-1.3.1.tgz"
    },
    "word-wrap": {
      "version": "1.2.3",
      "from": "word-wrap@>=1.2.3 <1.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/word-wrap/-/word-wrap-1.2.3.tgz"
    },
    "wrappy": {
      "version": "1.0.2",
      "from": "wrappy@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/wrappy/-/wrappy-1.0.2.tgz"
    },
    "write": {
      "version": "1.0.3",
      "from": "write@1.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/write/-/write-1.0.3.tgz"
    }
  }
}
```

```sh
$ node -v
v6.17.1
$ npm -v
3.10.10
$ ls
npm-shrinkwrap.json  package.json
$ npm install
...
```

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, it still doesn't work for me. I edited my question with the error output. In the future I'll be sure to use a lock file... thank you!